# Multiple job letter uploads for multiple UC schools?

Tags: job-search

My question is about applying to jobs at multiple different UC schools.
(To fix ideas, I'm in math and applying for jobs at the tenure-track level.) It appears that even though the UC schools all use the same online application system (it's called something like AP Recruit or Recruit), when you apply for several UC schools, you have to create separate accounts, fill in all the same biographical and contact information again and again -- and, most painfully, ask your letter writers to upload the same letter multiple times!
(In comparison for schools using Interfolio or MathJobs, a single upload each suffices.)

Is this really true? If so, how horrible! If not, what am I missing?

(Oh, and yes, I do know that I can pay Interfolio to manage the uploads for me. Perhaps I should have done that. I don't know. Right now I just want to make sure the horror I am seeing is real.)

Comment: I've heard that some high-level administrator in the UC system is (or was) preventing the use of MathJobs. Unfortunately, I don't remember the source of this information.

Comment: Some math job openings in California use mathjobs: https://www.mathjobs.org/jobs/Berkeley

Comment: That's how it works in the real world; and by real world, I mean anywhere that does not use mathjobs.org.

Comment: @AndreasBlass see [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/notices/201907/rnoti-p1085.pdf).

Comment: @EthanBolker No -- these positions are merely cross-posted at MathJobs. To apply you have to use the UC Recruit system.

Comment: @DanRomik Thanks! Very interesting. (And kinda depressing.)

Comment: But why was my question downvoted? Is it not a reasonable question? Not clearly posed? @AnonymousPhysicist

Comment: @user1931 you’re welcome. On the plus side, your letter writers are probably aware of this situation and understand that they’ll have to accept the minor hassle of uploading their letters to multiple sites. No one will think any of this is your fault, so don’t let this nonsense stand in your way. Good luck with the job search!

Comment: @DanRomik I basically agree that the American writers don't expect anything better than this. But I'm worried about the European letter writer -- I'm not sure he will understand. (Nor should he; it's cruel and incomprehensible.)

Comment: @user1931 send him a link to that article…

Comment: @user1931: European universities use a wide range of different application procedures and there certainly is nothing equivalent to mathjobs.org, so your letter writer is likely used to sending letters to different places.

Comment: @user1931 I did not vote, but there's a good argument this "question" contains the answer and shouldn't be here.  Complaints are not questions.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist :) Oh, I really don't think that's fair! When I initially posted I could not believe what I was seeing and I thought I was making a mistake. I agree that it's become more of a complaint as it becomes clearer that there was no mistake.

Comment: @PieterNaaijkens Actually in my (admittedly somewhat limited) experience, while European job applications do look varied and different, the letters all get mailed to an admin email address. Obviously emailing a letter to a human being is vastly preferable to the dreaded upload.